# How does enable_if works in this case

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

template<typename T = int> std::enable_if_t<!std::is_arithmetic<T>{}, T> nope() {}

int main() {
    nope();
}
```

This is a simple code which does't compile. If one changed this:

```
int main() {
        nope();
}
```

to

```
int main() {
        nope<std::string>();
}
```

it starts to compile.
The question is why does this work like it works? To be more specific why does compiler tells me:

> no matching function for call to 'nope()'

instead of something like

> enable_if::type not found
>   (which is true as it really does not exist if condition is not satisfied)?

Thank you.

Comment: Since your asking about why the compiler favors one error message over another, you should tag this question with the compiler you are using.

Comment: What you're seeing is called [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae).

Comment: Both GCC and Clang give decent error messages on this. Clang even gives `note: candidate template ignored: disabled by 'enable_if' [with T = int]
    using enable_if_t = typename enable_if<_Cond, _Tp>::type;`

Comment: It probably does tell you that. At least it does on [clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2b4221ec7b5a0429), [gcc](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e2529b7af0c3ff9a).

Comment: @nwp. Gcc does not, in my case (7.2)

Comment: That's odd, because [coliru uses gcc 7.2 too](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ace31c94985f8472) and produces the warning just fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you call `nope()`, your `template` type defaults to `int`. `std::enable_if_t<!std::is_arithmetic<T>{}, T>` returns `false` for `!std::is_arithmetic<int>{}` and fails.

A call to `nope<int>()` would also fail, for the same reasons as why `nope()` fails.

On the other hand, `nope<std::string>` gets `true` in `is_arithmetic` and returns a working function.

The compiler error that is triggered with `clang++` version 5.0 explains the outcome quite clearly:

> candidate template ignored: requirement '`!std::is_arithmetic<int>{}`' was not satisfied `[with T = int] std::enable_if_t<!std::is_arithmetic<T>{}, T> nope() {}`

Comment: Yes, I got this. But as I understand std::enable_if_t<!std::is_arithmetic<T>{}, T> does't return false as it's defined like so:
template< bool B, class T = void >
using enable_if_t = typename enable_if<B,T>::type;

Should it not raise compiler error since type is not defined in case B == false?

Comment: It does raise a compiler error, see @nwp's comment above. My GCC isn't too clear either, but the clang message is clear.